# Update and show different pictures with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I try to show diffrents prictures using pyQT5 but I did not understand how to do it. Now I can display just one image och tried to set a timer betwwen the first och second image but it does not work. Here my code

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import * 
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import * 
import sys

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 image - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 410
        self.initUI()
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
 
        label_img = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('charger_images/startingUp.png')
        label_img.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())

        timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_image)
        timer.start(60*1000)
        self.update_image()
     
    def update_image(self):
        label_img2 = QLabel(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap('charger_images/QRcode.png')
        label_img2.setPixmap(pixmap)
        self.resize(pixmap.width(),pixmap.height())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: Try saving the reference to `label_img` by making it an attribute of your app `self.label_img = QLabel(self)` in `initUI`. In `update_image`, set the pixmap of `self.label_img`, no need to create a new label every tick. Also why do you call `self.update_image()` immediately? I thought you wanted the new image to appear only after 60 seconds.

Comment: You should also keep a reference to the timer (`self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)`) so that you can stop/restart/change the timer.